# Numpy: What is a nice way to write functions that work for 1D and 2D arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I want to write a function f(x), which does the following:

- return g(x), if x is a 1D numpy array
- return np.array([g(xi) for xi in x]) if x is a 2D numpy array

<s>what would be a tidy way to implement functions like that?</s>

Is there a numpy-specific function to do this operation in one line, without writing if-statements?

Comment: It's really frustrating when somebody puts -1, but does not comment. If you see this, please improve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ndim` tells you the dimensions of the array-like:

```
def f(x):
    if np.ndim(x) == 1:
        return g(x)
    elif np.ndim(x) == 2:
        return np.array([g(xi) for xi in x])
    else:
        # Whatever you want to do with more than 2 directions
        return None
```

Comment: Yeah, this solution is rather obvious. But I was wondering if this is how you would actually do it. For example, the function np.sum(x, axis) behaves differently if the argument axis is provided. Would you use if-statement to distinguish between the two cases, as opposed to some built-in function like any or foreach?

Comment: For the problem in hand, when you want your function to behave differently when the dimensions are 1, or 2. If-statement is the simplest and best thing you've got, as opposed to some other complex logic.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Ever since I found out that np.sum() is faster than summing things in a for-loop, I try to be cautious with python

Comment: That is faster for different reasons, as `numpy` is mostly written in cython instead of python, which makes it a lot faster than your own python code.

Comment: This is not at all a numpythonic solution. Since the original question has unfortunately been stated in too broad terms there is no specific answer to it; but in practice youd never write code like this in idiomatic numpy.

Comment: np.apply_along_axis solves your problem in a more elegant manner; but it is basically syntactic sugar for your if-statements, performance wise. To actually get the most out of numpy, the crux lies in the way you write your function g to accomodate that; not in how you call it.

Answer (score 1):

A function g(x) that produces a scalar from a 1-D vector, can be extended to arbitrary higher dimensionality like this:

```
import numpy as np

def myfunc(x):
    return sum(x)

def f( g, x ):
    if len(x.shape) == 1:
        return g(x)
    if len(x.shape) > 1:
        return np.array( [f(g,v) for v in x] )

# Test with one dimensional input
res = f( myfunc, np.array( [0.,1.,2.] ) )
print( res )

# Test with two dimensional input
res = f( myfunc, np.array( [[0.,1.,2.],[3.,4.,5.]] ) )
print( res )

# And, still more dimensions
res = f( myfunc, np.ones( (3,2,2) ) )
print( res )
```

produces,

```
3.0

[  3.  12.]

[[ 2.  2.]
 [ 2.  2.]
 [ 2.  2.]]
```

Comment: Yeah, it is more or less the same as Muhammad's answer...

Comment: yes, i started while there was no answers, he typed faster.   but here is another trick, see the edit.

Comment: Uff, this forum is so competitive :( Grab a like :)

Comment: Thank you.  There is another trick, that might be of interest depending on your problem,  take a look at numpy vectorize().   At first glance, that one though seems to be for 1:1 output, were as you seemed to describe your need as one scalar out per 1-d vector input.   I started to work that one up as the answer before I noticed the dimensional reduction specified in the question.